# Hnadle Any JSON definition in Spring Rest controller from a request

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

I'm handling A JSON sent in POST Request body using:

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping
    public Library newLibrary(@RequestBody Library newLibrary) {
        return libraryRepository.saveAndFlush(newLibrary);
    }
```

**Library model**

```
    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

**JSON in Request Body**

```
{

    "name" : "testLibrary"
}
```

But my application won't receive definite JSON Structure in a call, for example, I receive something like this -

```
{   
    "names" : ["testLibrary","testLibrary2"],
    "anyKey" : "val",
    "anykey2" : {"keys":"vals"}
}
```

So I need to know how can I handle this situation in a single Post mapping function.

Comment: Do you want to read only `name` attribute from request json?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonAnySetter` annotation from jackson library.

Inside your model:

```
private Map<String, Object> details;

@JsonAnySetter
public void setDetail(String key, Object value) {
    if (null == details) {
        this.details = new HashMap<>();
    }
    this.details.put(key, value);
}
```

And it will put extra(not defined into model) fields into the map.

**Hope this helps!**